# How and when are variables casted to types declared in generic type parameters?

Tags: java, generics

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    integers.add(5); //element #0

    List list = integers;
    list.add("foo"); //element #1

    integers.get(1); //no error
    System.out.println(integers.get(1)); //no error, prints "foo"
    Integer i = integers.get(1); //throws ClassCastException

}
```

I'm trying to understand the process of casting variables of type, declared as a generic type parameter, and I'm a bit confused.
So, you may see in the example I've provided, that after we create a non-parametrized `List`, which refers to the same object that `List<Integer>`, then we can add any objects to that list (OK, nothing surprising here) and, what confuses me so much, we can extract non-`Integer` values from `List<Integer> integers`. Why isn't `ClassCastException` thrown at the first or the second call of `integers.get(1)`?

I assumed that methods returning parameter types, in fact always return `Object` and those returned values are implicitly tried to be converted to 
l-value type or method parameter type at runtime (as there are no generics at runtime), however the following test convinced me that `Integer` is always preferred over `Object`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    integers.add(5); //element #0

    List list = integers;
    list.add("foo"); //element #1

     print(integers.get(1));

}

private static void print(Object var) {
    System.out.println(var);
}

//this method is entered
private static void print(Integer var) { 
    System.out.println(var);
}

private static void print(String var) {
    System.out.println(var);
}
```

Another interesting fact is that although elements of `ArrayList` are stored in `Object[]` array, they are always converted to a type defined in type parameter before being returned in method `get()`:

```
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}

E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

So, if anyone may point me to the documentation where these questions are explained step by step, I would be very thankful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler inserts casts when casts are needed. The method `System.out.println` has a parameter of type `Object`, so no cast to `Integer` is required.

In the case of your three `print` methods, the method with a parameter of type `Integer` is chosen, so the compiler inserts a cast. The choice of which of the three methods to use occurs at *compile* time based on a complicated set of rules. These rules use the generic information to see that `integers.get(1)` has type `Integer`, and so the `Integer` version is chosen and the cast is needed. As a result, the code is more or less equivalent to `Java 4` code

```
List integers = new ArrayList();
integers.add("foo");
integers.add(Integer.valueOf(5));  // No autoboxing in Java 4!
print((Integer) integers.get(1));  // Cast inserted by compiler
```

The cast to `(E)` in the final part of your question does not actually do anything at runtime, and so will not throw a `ClassCastException`. It is only needed to make the code compile. You are telling the compiler that, yes, you are sure the `Object` is really an `E` and won't cause an exception later on (although you have subverted that by mixing raw and generic types).